# Pointers on Programs That Save User Settings

Tags: c++, xcode, save, settings, fstream

I've just finished my second semester of programming a week or so ago.  We've learned so much over the year, but haven't discussed building applications that save user settings, but we did discuss file variables, so I decided to try to build a program that saves user settings to a file.

I've got the program running and saving settings to a .txt file (using `Xcode` on Mac), but with this being my first time doing this

I'm sure I've committed some mistakes while doing it.  I'd like some pointers on how to improve it, maybe more elegant ways of doing it, or more conventional ways.  I'm certain my method for creating a folder is incorrect.  I also am not sure how to code the pathway so that it knows the username of the computer, I just hard-coded my pathway in (omitted for the sake of online post).

The program itself is trivial, it just builds a box, I was merely just trying to build an app that saved settings, I wasn't worried about what the program was doing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>//for functions in date function
#include <time.h> //for functions in date function
#include <sys/stat.h>//for mkdir functions
using namespace std;

int EmptyFileChecker(ifstream &FI, const char *P);
void RetrievePreviousSettings(ifstream &FI, char &BS, int &H, int &W, const char *P);
void EnterNewSettings(char &BS, int &H, int &W);
void BuildBox(const char &BS, const int &H, const int &W);
void SaveSettings(ofstream &FO, const char &BS, const int &H, const int &W, const char *P);
string Date();

int main()
{
    int Heighth=0;
    int Width=0;
    char BoxSymbol = '*';

    int UserChoice=0;//for making new settings or not
    int SaveSettingsFlag = 0;

    const char *Path = "/Users/MYUSERNAME/Library/Application Support/The Lyons' Den/TheLyons'DenBoxSettings.txt";//code variable for username

    ifstream FileIn;
    ofstream FileOut;

    mkdir("/Users/MYUSERNAME/Library/Application Support/The Lyons' Den", ACCESSPERMS);//MODE??

    if (EmptyFileChecker(FileIn, Path))
    {
        cout << "Previous settings detected.\n";
        cout << "Enter 1 to use old settings, 2 to enter new: ";

        cin >> UserChoice;

        if (UserChoice == 1)
            RetrievePreviousSettings(FileIn, BoxSymbol, Heighth, Width, Path);

        else
        {
            EnterNewSettings(BoxSymbol, Heighth, Width);
            SaveSettingsFlag = 1;
        }
    }

    else
    {
        EnterNewSettings(BoxSymbol, Heighth, Width);
        SaveSettingsFlag = 1;
    }

    BuildBox(BoxSymbol, Heighth, Width);

    if (SaveSettingsFlag)// only save new settings if new settings were entered
        SaveSettings(FileOut, BoxSymbol, Heighth, Width, Path);
}

int EmptyFileChecker(ifstream &FI, const char *P)
{
    FI.open(P);

    if (FI.fail())
        return 0;

    else if (FI.eof())
        return 0;

    else
        return 1;
}

void RetrievePreviousSettings(ifstream &FI, char &BS, int &H, int &W, const char *P)
{
    FI >> H;
    FI >> W;
    FI >> BS;

    cout << "\nHeighth: " << H << endl;
    cout << "Width: " << W << endl;
    cout << "Box Symbol: " << BS << endl;
}

void EnterNewSettings(char &BS, int &H, int &W)
{
    cout << "\nHeighth: ";

    cin >> H;

    cout << "\nWidth: ";

    cin >> W;

    cout << "\nBox Symbol: ";

    cin >> BS;
}

void BuildBox(const char &BS, const int &H, const int &W)
{
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 1; i <= H; i++)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= W; i++)
            cout << BS << " ";

        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;
}

void SaveSettings(ofstream &FO, const char &BS, const int &H, const int &W, const char *P)
{
    FO.open(P);

    if (FO.fail())
        cout << "Couldn't Open File\n";

    FO << H  << endl;
    FO << W  << endl;
    FO << BS << endl;

    FO << "Date of Settings: " << Date() << endl;
    FO << "Do not modify these settings manually";

    FO.close();
}

string Date()//not my code here - just modified it to read easier
{
    char Time[50];
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    strftime(Time, 50, "%b, %d, %Y", localtime(&now)); //short month name
    return string(Time);
}
```

Comment: There are [functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/URLsForDirectory:inDomains:) in Cocoa for retrieving "special" paths, but the preferred way on OS X is to use [`NSUserDefaults`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/). Or, you could do the Unix thing and save a "dot-file" (a file whose name begins with ".") in the user's home directory.

Comment: Hi Joe.  This problem would be better suited to a code review site; stackoverflow itself focuses on specific technical problems and their workarounds or solutions, rather than general reviews and tips.  You might check the posting guidlines at codereview.stackexhange.com, though I can't guarantee that site's suitable - I don't often visit any such sites.

Comment: Thanks Tony, didn't consider that SO wouldn't be useful for larger concept questions.  I'll take a look at your suggestion for where repost this.  Thanks.